# Разбор слова "грядочка" по составу

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Помогите разобрать слова *избеночка* и *грядочка* по составу.

Comment: Сделайте хоть какую-нибудь попытку, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что домашнее задание.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не актуальный для автора.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это д/з.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь разбор по составу **не совсем очевиден**:

1. Гряд/к/а - гряд/оч/к/а, суффикс ОЧ и К.

   > ГРЯДКА. Небольшая насыпь из вскопанной или привозной земли в огороде, цветнике и т. п.
2. Изб/а - изб/ёнк/а - изб/ёноч/к/а, суффиксы ЁНОЧ и К.

Comment: А суффикс "-оч-" сам по себе где-нибудь используется?

Comment: Нет, такого суффикса нет.

Comment: Ахем...  А у Вас там дроби стоят между "оч" и "к".  Это как понимать?  И "ёноч" как отдельный суффикс назван в (2)...  Это - ошибка или ...?

Comment: Был суффикс ЁНК, к нему добавилась беглая гласная, произошло чередование К/Ч, получился вариант ЁНОЧ. Аналогично был суффикс К,  нему добавилась беглая гласная, произошло чередование К/Ч, получился вариант ОЧ.

Comment: Не понял, извините.  В первом Вашем коментарии Вы сказали, что такого суффикса нет.  Так всё-таки есть?

Comment: Это разные морфы одного суффикса: К/ОЧ, ЁНК/ЁНОЧ. Беглые гласные часто входят в состав корня или суффикса:  шапк/а - шапоч/к/а, здесь два морфа у корня ШАПК/ШАПОЧ.

Comment: Ага.  Получается сдвоенный суффикс, так?  И такое мы наблюдаем только у ОЧ/К (ЁНОЧ/К)?

Comment: Это общая закономерность для различных суффиксов и корней: тропинка - тропинок.

Comment: У тропинки-то не одинаковый суффикс.  Вы же сказали, что "ОЧ" - по сути тот же "К".  "ИН" - всё таки не "К", или-таки "К" тоже?

Answer (score 0):

Грядочка- гряд корень
          Очк суффикс
          А окончание

Избеночка- изб корень
           Ён суффикс
           Очк суффикс
           А окончание!!!!